# the ordinal numbers before names

Tags: numbers

I am not sure how to read the number after the name of monarchs? For example Louis XVI. Is the only way Louis *the sixteenth* or is it possible Louis *sixteen*?

Comment: The man-in-the-street says "Louis the Sixteenth" or "Pope Pius the Tenth".

Comment: @TRomano and in my dialect, he's the man-**on**-the-street, but it appears I'm in the minority according to [Google Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=man+in+the+street%2C+man+on+the+street&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cman%20in%20the%20street%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bman%20in%20the%20street%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BMan%20in%20the%20Street%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cman%20on%20the%20street%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bman%20on%20the%20street%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BMan%20on%20the%20Street%3B%2Cc0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The numbers that follow the names of monarchs are read with the definite article and as *ordinals*.  In your case,

> Louis XVI

is "Loo-ee the Sixteenth" (the 's' in 'Louis' is silent)

Comment: It's in French 'Louis' only.  Since that Louis was a French king, the 's' is silent. The name of the American city St. Louis has 's' pronounced.

Comment: You'll also see it pronounced 'seize' (french for 16 (they use sixteen not sixteenth)) in english, perhaps it is occuring more often when talking about antiquities.